# window.open function blocked as popup in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser

```
// NEW CODE
setTimeout(function() { 
 if (confirm('Hello... Wanna chat?'))
 {
   window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
 } 
}, 1000);
```

I finally got this code changed and working to open the page in another tab but every browser blocks the page open as a popup! Idk what to do about it. Using stackoverflow site as a placeholder here. Anyone have any ideas?

```
// OLD CODE
setTimeout(function() { 
 if (confirm('Hello... Wanna chat?'))
 {
   window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
 } 
}, 10000);
```

This is the original code that didn't open in a new window but it worked fine and was never blocked as a popup. I couldn't get _blank to work with window.location.href so that's why it is window.open now. The time difference also made no difference (1000 vs. 10000) I tested it.

If anyone has any solutions I am open to try. The idea is just a popup that you can click 'Ok' to go to (in a new tab) or 'Cancel' to close. I don't want it blocked as a popup instead of opening the new tab when clicking 'Okay'. Thanks!!

Comment: The `confirm()` function is not directly considered a human action, so it will get blocked by popup blockers. Your solution could be to create your own confirm box in HTML and CSS, and then make the button(s) open a link.

Comment: @Steffen is that an easy thing to implement? I am fine with the default browser popup I just cannot figure out a way to make it open a page in a new tab without being blocked. I don't get why opening over the current page is allowed but confirm() when used with window.open and _blank is blocked?? that's what's so frustrating!